# Current status of the linearity of mapping class group

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, noncommutative-geometry, symplectic-topology

In the paper [A faithful linear-categorical action of the mapping class group of a surface with boundary](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1032v2) it is claimed that it was (as of 2014) still unknown that mapping class group is linear, but the authors provide a faithful linear-categorical action of the mapping class group of a surface with necessarily non-empty boundary using knot Floer homology that does not seem decategorifiable in a non-trivial way.

On the other hand, there exists the following paper, [Mapping class groups are linear](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312449v8), in which the author uses the non-commutative machinery to prove that they are. As I have asked in [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/216204/are-all-transversely-oriented-foliations-given-by-closed-forms) question, there might perhaps be a mistake in one of the proof ingredients.

Hence the question: is it known that a mapping class group of some surface (possibly with non-empty boundary or non-zero number of punctures) is linear?

Comment: I changed the arXiv links to point to the abstract pages.

Comment: The paper ``Mapping class groups are linear'' was [published](https://doi.org/10.1515/9783110413557-012) in 2018 as part of the de Gruyter book _Topological Algebras and Their Applications: Proceedings of the 8th International Conference on Topological Algebras and Their Applications, 2014_.  Is the paper believed to be correct at this point, or is this still under dispute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. There [is the paper by Bigelow, and our own Ryan Budney](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0010310.pdf), who do this for genus 2. I believe that is still the last word.